# Mailchimp signup form is not working subscribe button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/uLn0cr09/):

When i run this code, when i click subscribe button, Nothing happened.

I m trying to change the location placing code, but still i couldn't find the mistake.

```
<div class='popup'>
<div class='cnt223'>
<img src='http://s14.postimg.org/w3j8ay2bh/1440412582_cross_24.png' 
alt='quit' class='x' id='x' />
<p>
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action"//wafytech.us11.list-manage.com/subscribe
/post?u=4cc1d72c9827dd3ef80675e4c&amp;id=4d5daa8c14" method="post" id="mc-
embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" 
target="_blank" novalidate>
 <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
    <h2>Subscribe to our mailing list</h2>
<div class="indicates-required"><span class="asterisk">*</span> indicates 
required</div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
    <label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
</label>
    <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-
EMAIL">
</div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
    <label for="mce-FNAME">First Name </label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="FNAME" class="" id="mce-FNAME">
</div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
    <label for="mce-LNAME">Last Name </label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="LNAME" class="" id="mce-LNAME">
</div>
    <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
        <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
        <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
    </div>    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good 
things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;"><input type="text" 
name="b_4cc1d72c9827dd3ef80675e4c_4d5daa8c14" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
    <div class="clear">
    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-
subscribe" class="button"></div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
<br/>
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have an error on an external script. Move it to the end of the document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because you have http://s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/mc-validate.js loading before the document finishes loading.

On line 196, you have the following:

```
    getAjaxSubmitUrl: function() {
        var url = $("form#mc-embedded-subscribe-form").attr("action");
        url = url.replace("/post?u=", "/post-json?u=");
        url += "&c=?";
        return url;
    },
```

It is giving me errors on `url = url.replace("/post?u=", "/post-json?u=");` because `$("form#mc-embedded-subscribe-form")` can't fetch the right element due to the document not being loaded. As a consequence, `.attr("action")` will return `undefined`. Try adding a `.ready` event listener to the whole code.

Also, the right way is `$("#mc-embedded-subscribe-form")`.

---

To add on that, you also have this on your HTML:

```
<form action"[...]">
```

You forgot the `=` between `action` and its value. It should look like this:

```
<form action="[...]">
```

Notice the `=` there!

Comment: @saina What aren't you understanding?

Comment: @saina Are you the owner/maintainer of http://s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/mc-validate.js  ?

Comment: Then you have to move the file to the end of the document

Comment: yes.. it is end of my file index.html .. i placed before the closing </body>

Comment: No problem. I'm glad I've helped

Comment: hi.. one more help.. i set cookies by manual for this task.. may i know.. is there any popup form in mailchimp with cookies .

Comment: @saina I absolutelly have no idea. I'm really sorry